# Не наследуется класс в python-docx бибиотеке

Tags: python, классы, python-docx

Почему-то выбивает ошибку при наследовании класса Document.

Код:

```
from docx import Document

class MyDoc(Document):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.save("WTF.docx")

if __name__=="__main__":
   dc = MyDoc()
```

Ошибка:

> TypeError: function() argument 'code' must be code, not str

Указывает на строку "class MyDoc(Document):"

Как будто Document - это строка.
Но ведь при использовании в библиотеке можно убедиться, что это класс. Пример использования Document:

```
from docx import Document

if __name__=="__main__":

    dc = Document()
    dc.save("WTF.docx")
```

И этот код работает.

В чем проблема???

Comment: >>> type(Document)
<class 'function'>

Comment: Похоже, `Document` это функция

Comment: @splash58 а что будет если написать `type(Document())`?

Comment: <class 'docx.document.Document'>

Comment: class MyDoc(Document()):
 pass

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    class MyDoc(Document()):
TypeError: __init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Comment: попробуйте место `class MyDoc(Document):` написать `class MyDoc(type(Document()):`

Comment: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html?highlight=Document%20objects#id1  Not intended to be constructed directly. Use docx.Document() to open or create a document.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39874269/subclassing-a-function-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Document` это функция которая возвращает экземпляр класса.

Мы должны получить экземпляр класса, а потом с помощью `type` узнать экземпляром какого класса он является

```
class MyDoc(type(Document())):
```

Comment: перейди по моему последнему комментарию

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем, кто помог. Но способ с type не работает. Не по причинам того, что способ неправильный, а , видимо, из-за особенностей библиотеки.
Выбивает ошибку:

> TypeError: **init**() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'element' and 'part'

Скорее всего в недрах библиотеки Document Имеет какие-то принимаемые значения в конструкторе. Копаться в этом не сильно хочется, вряд ли будет какой-то не костыльный способ. Проще уж тогда не наследовать класс, а писать код по-другому.

Всем спасибо, но если будут идеи, как можно просто это сделать, то пишите, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: перейдите по моей последней ссылке - там решение есть